# Creator's Update - intl.cpl (Region) seemingly broken

Tags: windows-10, control-panel, windows-10-v1703, regional-settings

I was trying to access `intl.cpl` for region-related settings, specifically changing lockscreen date/time format and language. I noticed that when I click the corresponding item or run the `cpl` from Run, nothing appears.

Monitoring processes with `procexp` reveals that the process `control` and `rundll32` responsible for the panel is run, but then `rundll32` starts `WerFault` and all processes quit briefly after, which means they errored out.

**EDIT:** I could access the panel via `Control Panel -> Clock, Language and Region -> Language -> Advanced settings -> Apply language settings to the welcome screen...`, which takes me to the `Administrative` card of the panel, but when I click on the `Formats` panel (needed to change time format), it errors out with "Windows Shell Common Dll has stopped working".

This only happens on the PC I just fresh installed Creator's Update on - the other PC with the former version works fine.

Did another fresh install, and the problem persists.

Ideas?

Comment: While I don't know why it is not working for you, I have the latest version of Windows and **intl.cpl** works as it always did. See this screen recording  http://i.imgur.com/GmeT2U9.gifv

Comment: I'm starting to think my installation has some problems, as random operations will freeze and restart `explorer`, along with other weird symptoms. Since it's a fresh install with no important data, I might as well try starting over again today.

Comment: An easy way to do it would be with the Windows 10 refresh Tool https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10startfresh

Comment: I have the ISO on hand so I think I'll just use that. Thanks for the mention anyway.

Comment: I though that the installation media you have misses somehow something, so doing it with the refresh tool will have Windows downloading all from start and verifying it.

Comment: Hmm, that is a possibility, although I did download my ISO from a MSDN mirror. If reinstalling from ISO still doesn't work, then I definitely need to try your tip.

Comment: werfault means the app crashes. [create crash dumps](https://pastebin.com/zKuJvw57) and share the dumps