# Losing ability to adjust brightness after every cold boot

Tags: windows-10, brightness, display-driver

My tablet comes with Atom x5 Z8300 and its built-in Intel HD Graphics. I have wiped out its old, pre-installed Windows 10 v10240 and installed Creators Update  myself, but I also took the time to back up the original drivers with DISM.

Problem: every time I do a cold boot (i.e. chose "shut down" before), the tablet loses its ability to adjust brightness, locking it at its last value regardless of what the OS shows when I press the adjustment keys or tiles. I could get to where I backed up my drivers, restore the graphics driver alone, and *reboot* (not *shut down*), and brightness adjustment will come back, until I decide to shut it down again next time.

From what Device Manager tells me, the driver version between boots are identical, so I reckon this eliminates the possibility of Windows 10 automatically installing a new driver. Also, I already turned off automatic driver updates in Group Policy.

**EDIT:**

- I tried using DDU to clean up and uninstall the driver, then reinstall it from my DISM backup. Still no go.
- The famous [FeatureTestControl registry trick](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/intel-hd-graphics-4000-and-windows-10-64bit/768697b3-0013-4e13-862c-bbdd03247275) and its variants don't work either.

Since it's a tablet I only use once in a while, but only used in emergency, I can't just avoid shutting it down and call it a day, nor can I afford to do the driver restoration steps when I need it ready quickly.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by doing a downgrade (fresh install of Anniversary Update). Been experiencing other quirks with Creator's Update (e.g. [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1207333/creators-update-intl-cpl-region-seemingly-broken)), so downgrade was a reasonable choice for me.